# Data still in storage after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-note-3, hard-reset

I am trying to sell my Note 3 and performed a factory reset both from the Home + Power + Volume Up menu, as well as the settings -> Factory reset menu.

Both approaches seem successful at resetting the device as nothing remains on the phone's interface and I go through all the screen like the first day I bought it.

The only issue is when I connect the device to the computer via USB, it appears all the data is still in storage, just not on the user interface of the phone. Any idea why this is?

I would like to completely wipe everything off the phone so the storage is as empty as it can be.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an external storage try formatting the external SD card. You can do it in the computer or in Android it should be under Storage.

Comment: Music, Pictures, Apps, etc in the Phone->Android directory

Comment: Are you sure they have your content? They might be just empty directories or with initial data of the app. Try adding fake content.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do the factory reset through the system settings menu? If so you must make sure to select removal of all user data. Otherwise the data is likely just on external storage.